# Error during only Debug of program. (In dll of Oculus HMD)

Tags: visual-studio, dll, oculus

I am using Oculus World Demo.
I can start it manually, but I have an internal error during "Debug"/"Release".

How to debug such errors?

Where can I see the command which runs the program.

Again: 
It runs normally when I click on MyGreatestApp.exe in folder /Debug/.
It has an internal error of used DLL, when I start it in VS2103. (something like -3003 or fffff447)

P.S. I find it strange that I can debug in "Release" mode.(I mean step-by-step program execution.) Is it normal? Maybe I do it wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Add a comment about downvote, please. Did I violate something? (possibly good idea for meta - connect downvote with reason in several words, in order to see what is wrong)

Answer (score 0):

It could be useful if you say in what line the program crash.

Anyway you can use the Oculus Debug Tool: https://developer3.oculus.com/documentation/pcsdk/latest/concepts/dg-debug-tool/

To record logs and see at the Runtime side what is happening.

This is error -3003, check why your application is not connecting to Oculus. I should check if I running the 64 bit of my application or something like that.

```
ovrError_ServiceConnection          = -3003,   ///< Couldn't connect to the OVR Service.
```

Hope it helps